# Upgrade pip on Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I want to upgrade pip 7.1.2 to pip 9.0.1, how can I do it? I am using Python on Windows 10. I tried using the command- -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: That should work, but you need the word "python" just before it: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`. Is that what you did?

Comment: Thanks I succeed, I actually had to create/define the running environment for python in my settings in order to access python and pip commands through Windows CMD